# Runtime Error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I run this program in Ideone.com and get a runtime error. Could anyone suggest softwares to debug runtime errors in Linux. EVerytime asking such doubts on stackoverflow will be avoided

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node{
    int num;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

void push(Node **head,int num){
    Node *newnode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newnode->num = num;
    newnode->next = *head;
    *head = newnode;
}

void palindrome(Node **front){
    int *res = 1;
    isPalindrome(front,*front,res); 
    if(*res == 0)
        printf("Not a Palindrome");
    else
        printf("Palindrome");
}

void isPalindrome(Node **front,Node *back,int *res){
    if(back == NULL)
        return;
    isPalindrome(front,back->next,res);
    if(*res == 0)
        return;
    if((*front)->num != back->num)
        *res = 0;
    *front = (*front)->next;
}

int main(void){
    Node *head = NULL;
    push(&head,1);
    push(&head,2);
    push(&head,2);
    push(&head,1);
    palindrome(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Use a debugger. For C programs on Linux this typically would be gdb.

Comment: if your are using linux, try gdb.

Comment: it just says segmentation fault(core dumped)

Comment: This `int *res = 1;` looks very sick.

Comment: res shouldn't be a pointer. You should make isPalindrome() return the result

Comment: It shouldn't be a pointer. See the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard debugger on Linux: [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/).

To debug a C or C++ program you should compile it with `-g` option first and, preferably, switched off optimization: `-O0`.

`gdb` is a command line program, working in text mode. There is a few graphical debuggers for Linux, too, they are usually just GUI for gdb. Use your favourite Internet search engine to find them.

Answer (score 1):

I think your method `palindrome` should look like this:

```
void palindrome(Node **front){
  int res = 1;
  isPalindrome(front,*front,&res); 
if(res == 0)
    printf("Not a Palindrome");
else
    printf("Palindrome");
}
```

In your implementation of this method you first creating pointer to `int` and assign it memory address 0x0000001 and then you dereference it that causes runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your palindrome function on the line:

```
int *res = 1;
```

You're setting the value of the pointer to 1 instead of the value of the variable. It should be,

```
int res = 1;
```

and then when you call isPalindrome you should do:

```
isPalindrome(front,*front, &res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int *res = 1;
```

Firstly this line should throw an error. Syntactically correct would be

```
int *res = (int*)1;
```

Even now you'd get undefined behaviour because you've not got res via malloc. And in later part you're doing this.